# Error reading a .stp file with Assimp library

Tags: assimp

So I've been trying to read a .stp file with the latest assimp library.
The error I get is:  "ERROR: Failed to load file: IFC: Unrecognized file schema: AUTOMOTIVE_DESIGN".

On the chance that my file was corrupted, I took a wavefront file I had and exported it to '.stp' using 'assimp' and I get the same error as above when I try to read the file back with assimp.

Would anyone have a clue about the file schema error with assimp or why assimp will not read a file it created?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Asset-Importer-Lib does only support the IFC-2.3-Format. So when the file format does not contain the following tag:

```
FILE_SCHEMA( ( 'IFC2X3' ) );
```

the import will fail at the moment. SO you can try to change this schema entr.

It would be nice to get your model for a deeper investigation ( just use our github-page: https://github.com/assimp )

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately I can't post the model.  I was able to create a .stp file from a wavefront with assimp which produced the same error when I tried to read back the .stp with assimp.